# copy text content from textblock within the datagrid wpf

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls

I need to copy the text content of the wpf Text block.
I am having a text block within a DataGrid I need to copy the text of the textblock on selecting the datarow .

my xaml code  is here ..

```
  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ScenarioTraceLogDetails}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" 
                                                RowHeaderWidth="0" Margin="10,0,10,10" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="14">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Log Description" Width="4*" MinWidth="550" IsReadOnly="True" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="TestAutomationClient:ScenarioTraceLogDetailWrapper">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LogDetail.Data}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding Path=LogDetail.LogType}" CanUserResize="True" Width="120" MinWidth="120" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Category" Binding="{Binding Path=LogDetail.Category}"  Width="150" MinWidth="150" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Start Time" Binding="{Binding Path=LogDetail.StartTime}"  Width="150" MinWidth="150" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Completion Time" Binding="{Binding Path=LogDetail.CompletionTime}"  MinWidth="150" Width="150" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Duration (~ms)" Binding="{Binding Path=TimeTaken}"  Width="120" MinWidth="120" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGrid.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsError}" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsWarning}" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkOrange" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSuccessfulInformation}" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=ScriptDatasetInfo}" />
                        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowDuration" Value="60000" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.Resources>
            </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Before answering your question, Do you using MVVM pattern?

Comment: yes i am using mvvm pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MVVM pattern, You have to create the following command on your ViewModel that copy the content of your TextBox:

```
public ICommand CopyValueCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new CommandHandler(

                    () => 
                         // Here your Text box should bind a property of your model
                         // Copy your model property value to ClipBoard
                         Clipboard.SetText(this.SelectedElement.YourProperty));
            }
        }
```

Then on XAML, use System.Windows.Interactivity to invoke your command when your DataGrid Selection is changed:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedElement, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  >
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=CopyValueCommand}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                ...
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

#### Remark

- I supposed that your TextBox text binding a property of your model.
- Note that you need to reference System.Windows.Interactivity.dll to your project. 
  I hope this helps you!

Comment: thanks ..How can i bing the property of the model to the text block.?

Comment: @Gowthaman Share your XAML code (at least the code of DataGrid) to help you on.

Comment: @Gowthaman I uploaded the visual studio project, download the sample and let me know if you are going right https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwSNnbUsies3YjVhMWROZ0tzVmM/view?usp=sharing